# Change HTML Table Caption BG Color With CSS

Tags: html, css

Can the background color on a table's caption be changed with CSS?

The captions on my tables are currently using the background behind them and I would like to make the caption's background a different color.
If so what is the CSS property ?

Here is my current CSS

```
.Table {
margin:0px;padding:0px;
width:100%;
border:1px solid #4c4040;

-moz-border-radius-bottomleft:8px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:8px;
border-bottom-left-radius:8px;

-moz-border-radius-bottomright:8px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:8px;
border-bottom-right-radius:8px;

-moz-border-radius-topright:8px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius:8px;
border-top-right-radius:8px;

-moz-border-radius-topleft:8px;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius:8px;
border-top-left-radius:8px;
}

.Table table{
border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
margin:0px;padding:0px;
}
```

And my HTML

```
<div class="Table" >
    <table align='center'  summary='blank Sum'>
      <caption><br>
      Please enter the Emails  of the people you want to invite.
      <br> <br>
      </caption>
      <tr>
        <td>Party ID</td><td>Party Name</td><td>Date</td><td>Sales</td>
        <td>blah</td>    <td>blah</td>      <td>blah</td><td>blah</td>
      </tr>     
    </table>

</div>
```

Comment: Sure why not? Have you tried styling the caption element? `caption {...}`

Comment: @j08691 Well I didn't know of the property. until now. Thankyou

Comment: The caption is an element like every other element. Nothing magical about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick answer

[Have a fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/9F6QG/)

CSS

```
table caption { background: #F00; }
```

---

**Slower Answer**

The `.Table` `div` seems superfluous. I would have something like this:

[Have a fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/gA4rA/)

HTML

```
<table summary='blank Sum'>
  <caption>
  Please enter the Emails  of the people you want to invite.
  </caption>

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Party ID</th>
            <th>Party Name</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Sales</th>
        </tr>
    </thead> 

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>Content</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>   
</table>
```

CSS

```
table { 
    width: 500px; /* whatever width */
    margin: 0 auto; /*center table*/
}

table caption { 
    padding: 10px;
    background: #F00;
}
```

Comment: No worries :) Have a look at my second example, it's a good starting point for you.